# SWISH Prolog Errors in Factorial

Tags: prolog, factorial

```
fact(0,1).
fact(N,F):-
    (   
        N>0:-
        (   N1 is N-1,
            fact(N1,f1),
            F is N*F1
        )
    ;   
    write("N less than 0 nor allowed")
    ).
```

In the tutorial, the authors code is working. I have written the same code but mine is not working. He is writing in cgwin (i.e. offline) and I am writing in SWISH (i.e. online).

Query passed: `fact(3,R).`
Error message:

```
Singleton variables: [R]
Singleton variables: [F1]
procedure `(A:-B)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      fact(A,B)
```

Comment: change `N>0:-` to `N>0 ->`

Comment: What tutorial, what author? You probably have made mistakes while copying.